# Why does this regex not seem to work?

Tags: java, regex

I have string that I want to replace in a file, when I see `hostName=some_word` I want to replace it with `some_other_word` but the zero-width negative lookbehind regex I use seems to be failing in the java code despite working when I tested it on an online java regex tester.

```
line = "hostName=testing"
Pattern host = Pattern.compile("(?<=hostName=).*");
Matcher match = host.matcher(line);
hostName = match.group(); //illegal state exception
line.replace(hostName,"new_name");
```

I tried that regex on a string online and it seemed to work fine:

link:
`http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/#!;t=hostName%3Dtesting&r=(%3F%3C%3DhostName%3D).*&x=new_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke `matcher.find()` (match within input) or `matcher.matches()` (whole input match) before invoking `matcher.group()`.

Typically within an `if` condition (or a `while` loop if iterating over matches).

See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) for `Matcher.group()`:

> **Throws:**
>
> IllegalStateException - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the
>   previous match operation failed

Comment: Okay, yes this is definitely the issue thanks! Annoying that the java docs don't mention anything about running the find() command before grouping

Comment: @sreya don't be too hard on yourself - it's easy to miss.